# discord.js RichEmbed issue

Tags: discord.js

I want the bot to download data from the MySQL database and add appropriate fields to the embed, and after entering the command, it sends an empty embed. There are no errors in output.
My code:

```
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
    name: "support",
    category: "Bot",
    description: "wyświetla ekipe bota",
    usage: `support`,
    run: async (client, message, connection) => {
        var embed = new RichEmbed()
        connection.query(`SELECT id FROM support WHERE ranga = '1'`, (err, rows) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            if (rows.length < 1) return;
            for (const element of rows) {
                osoba = client.users.find(user => user.id == `${element.id}`);
                embed.addField("Główny Developer", `${osoba.tag}`)
              }
        })
        connection.query(`SELECT id FROM support WHERE ranga = '2'`, (err, rows) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            if (rows.length < 1) return;
            for (const element of rows) {
                osoba = client.users.find(user => user.id == `${element.id}`);
                embed.addField("Developer", `${osoba.tag}`)
              }
        })
        connection.query(`SELECT id FROM support WHERE ranga = '3'`, (err, rows) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            if (rows.length < 1) return;
            for (const element of rows) {
                osoba = client.users.find(user => user.id == `${element.id}`);
                embed.addField("Support", `${osoba.tag}`)
              }
        })
        connection.query(`SELECT id FROM support WHERE ranga = '4'`, (err, rows) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            if (rows.length < 1) return;
            for (const element of rows) {
                osoba = client.users.find(user => user.id == `${element.id}`);
                embed.addField("Grafik", `${osoba.tag}`)
              }
        })
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }}
```

Comment: Did you try to log the rows?

Comment: Everything is fine with the data in MySQL, it looks like embed doesn't add Fields. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: No, I meant, can you try to console.log the `rows` and even `osoba`

Comment: yes it works and displays.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you are using v12, the rich embed is now MessageEmbed.

**EDIT** I never really explained it clearly, sorry. Change RichEmbed to MessageEmbed

Comment: I don't think he's using v12, he mentioned that it's sending an empty embed